# Брутфорс  почтовых индексов

Tags: брутфорс

Здравствуйте!

Хочу собрать безобидную таблицу почтовых индексов. Нашел сайт, который выдаёт по GET запросу ответ об актуальности почтового индекса. Проверил несколько режимов:

1. 1000 в секунду - на первой же тысяче блочат IP
2. 100 в секунду - блочат IP
3. 10 в секунду - не блочат

На следующее утро звонят из компании поставщика услуг интернета и говорят, что поступила на меня наводка мол с моего пользователя атакуют правительственный сервер 8-)

Вопрос: GET запрос вполне безобидный. На какой скорости приемлемо собирать нужную мне таблицу, чтобы точно не попасть под раздачу?

Comment: может связаться с админом сайта и попросить список? Не думаю, что это большой секрет. Объясните ему, что вам для таких-то целей, не для конкуренции, может и даст=) это не ответ на ваш вопрос, просто мысли вслух. Мне сайт webproverka com давал список мошенников, после небольшого разговора, так что это вполне реально.

Comment: попробую. отпишусь. спасибо за совет

Comment: http://www.geopostcodes.com/buy

Comment: :-) платно - не интересно и тем более, что вопрос ведь не где достать, а почему за многочисленные запросы к открытой в принципе информации вешают ярлык

Comment: просто у них паника :) Запилите через tor :)

Comment: http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/ м?

Comment: @thunder, оГО! не дурно, спасибо. жаль не все, но для начала в самый раз!

Comment: да погуглите на тему `post codes list download`, там много вылезло :) можно еще в начало добавить `russian`

Comment: @spirit, в общем первый их ответ был что-то вроде предупреждения, "а знаете ли вы сколько это весит", я подтвердил и после череды переадресовок получил от них предложение подписать контракт и оплатить услугу. Если бы мне это было нужно для бизнеса - это одно дело, а так.. выбор то есть.

Comment: жадные они))

Comment: А почему бы просто не спарсить [http://indexp.ru/][1] ?


  [1]: http://indexp.ru/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы на коленке собрал некий сервис, который в несколько потоков подключается к сайту через прокси лист (ну возьмем 100 адресов) и потихоньку, 10 запросов в секунду, делает своё дело. 10*100 = вот ваша и 1000 запросов. Благо бесплатных листов море.

Comment: код на джаве собрал :-) так как нагрузка на проц не особая, оттестил в домашних условиях на 1000 потоков - меньше чем 25% ресурсов. А вот прокси анонимные предстоит найти - это раз. Во вторых этож насколько скорость каждого запроса снизится? В общем всё самое интересное ещё впереди ;)

Comment: @qpaycm тут 1gb.ru раздает халявные сервера на пару суток. Если нет собственного сервера/vps, можно у них попробовать. С проксями не заморачивайтесь, но и из дома не следует запускать такое дело.

Comment: спасибо. учту